# Want to transfer data using livedata, viewmodel between in android fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am currently trying to make a app that calculates a loan plan. User plots in data like loan amount, downpayment years, and how much rent the loan should have. I have implemented edit text for the loan amount, two seekbars for years and rent number.

Since I am fairly new to android programing I am nautraly struggling with implementing MVVM to my app. I implemented databinding, viewmodel and wrote the code to link them togehter. I also get the value out if I use Init in viewmodel, but I dont seem to transfer Int value from seekbar to the next fragment. Do anyone has suggestion to my code?

I am gratefull for any help.

---

In AnnuitetFragment.kt fragment I have only implemented modelView to RenterAnnSeekBar since I use it for testing.

```
package com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.annuitet

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.R
import com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.databinding.FragmentAnnuitetBinding
import com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.viewmodel.AnnuitetViewModel


class AnnuitetFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAnnuitetBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    private lateinit var viewModel: AnnuitetViewModel


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

        _binding = FragmentAnnuitetBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

        var startPoint = 0
        var endPoint = 0

        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            binding.lifecycleOwner = this
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[AnnuitetViewModel::class.java]
            binding.viewmodel = viewModel




            binding.tilbakeTilVelkommen.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_annuitetFragment_to_velkommenFragment)
            }
            binding.BeregnLaanAnnuitet.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_annuitetFragment_to_annuitetPlanFragment)
            }


            binding.RenterAnnSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                    binding.RenterTall.text = progress.toString()
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                    if (seekBar != null){
                        startPoint = seekBar.progress
                    }

                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                    if (seekBar != null){
                        endPoint = seekBar.progress
                    }
                }
            })

            binding.AarSerieSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                    binding.AarTall.text = progress.toString()
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                    if (seekBar != null){
                        startPoint = seekBar.progress
                    }

                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
                    if (seekBar != null){
                        endPoint = seekBar.progress
                    }
                }
            })


    }
}
```

AnnuitetViewModel.kt is the viewmodel class I am going to use to store livedata so it can share it between AnnuitetFragment.kt and AnnuitetPlanFragment.kt. If this code miss any please help me with some pointers.

```
package com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.viewmodel

import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

open class AnnuitetViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val progress: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Int>() }

    val renterProgress: LiveData<Int>
        get() = progress

    init {
        progress.value = 1
    }
}
```

My plan AnnuitetPlanFragment.kt is to get data from AnnuitetFragment.kt and calculate the loan plan from user. But when I try to get the data from AnnuitViewModel.kt I get the mock data from Init but there is not data from val progress.

```
package com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.annuitet

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.R
import com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.databinding.FragmentAnnuitetBinding
import com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.databinding.FragmentAnnuitetPlanBinding

import com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.viewmodel.AnnuitetViewModel
import kotlin.math.pow

class AnnuitetPlanFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAnnuitetPlanBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var viewModel: AnnuitetViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                                savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = FragmentAnnuitetPlanBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(AnnuitetViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewmodel = viewModel

        viewModel.renterProgress.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { renteTall->
            binding.tvTest.text = renteTall.toString()
        })



        binding.tilbakeTilAnnuitet.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_annuitetPlanFragment_to_annuitetFragment)
        }

    }
}
```

Last one is my fragment_annuitet.xml where I implemented databinding and seekbar gets progress data and show it in viewCreate.

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
                <import type="android.view.View"/>
                <variable
                    name="viewmodel"
                    type="com.example.lnognedbetalingsplan.viewmodel.AnnuitetViewModel" />
        </data>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/annuitet_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".annuitet.AnnuitetFragment">

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/RenterAnnSeekBar"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:max="50"
                    android:min="0"
                    android:progress="@={viewmodel.progress}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/AarSerieSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.306"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.84" />

                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/AarSerieSeekBar"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:max="50"
                    android:min="0"
                    android:progress="5"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.306"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/laanebelop"
                    android:layout_width="196dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:autofillHints=""
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/hint"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textColorHint="#757575"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:text=""
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.641"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.248" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Laanebelop"
                    android:layout_width="103dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="184dp"
                    android:text="@string/laaneBeløp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.11"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AarTall"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/_5"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.619"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/AarSerieSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/RenterTall"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@={`` + viewmodel.progress}"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="@{viewmodel.progress != null? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.633"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/RenterAnnSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.383" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Rentenummer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/velg_rente"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RenterAnnSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.097"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Laanebelop"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.692" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/antallAar"
                    android:layout_width="62dp"
                    android:layout_height="21dp"
                    android:text="@string/antall_aar"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/AarSerieSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.097"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RenterAnnSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.666" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BeregnLaanAnnuitet"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="264dp"
                    android:text="@string/bergen_l_net"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.757"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/AarSerieSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/tilbakeTilVelkommen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
                    android:text="@string/tilbake"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/laanebelop"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/annuitet_l_n"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Laanebelop"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tilbakeTilVelkommen"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.066" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my own question out.

If found out if you share your modelview with the two fragments you want to share data bewteen, and with observer this is possible.

Added this code:

```
private val AnnuitetViewModel: AnnuitetViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Also made observers for every val I wanted to transfer to the next fragment:

```
AnnuitetViewModel.loanNumber.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){loanNumber->
                binding.laanebelop.setText(loanNumber)
            }

            AnnuitetViewModel.progressRenter.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){progressRenter->
                binding.RenterTall.text = progressRenter
            }

            AnnuitetViewModel.progressAar.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){progressAar->
                binding.AarTall.text = progressAar
            }
```

A button listner trigger the transfer to livedata in the viewmodel:

```
binding.BeregnLaanAnnuitet.setOnClickListener {
                AnnuitetViewModel.saveLoanNumber(binding.laanebelop.text.toString())
                AnnuitetViewModel.saveProgressRenter(binding.RenterTall.text.toString())
                AnnuitetViewModel.saveProgressAar(binding.AarTall.text.toString())
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_annuitetFragment_to_annuitetPlanFragment)
            }
```

In the viewModel I made some var and val that takes inn the data:

```
open class AnnuitetViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var startPoint = 0
    var endPoint = 0

    val seekbarRenterProgress: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Int>() }
    val seekbarAarProgress: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Int>() }

    private var _loanNumber = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val loanNumber: MutableLiveData<String> = _loanNumber

    fun saveLoanNumber(newLoanNumber: String){
        _loanNumber.value = newLoanNumber
    }

    private var _progressRenter = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val progressRenter: MutableLiveData<String> = _progressRenter

    fun saveProgressRenter(newProgressRenter: String){
        _progressRenter.value = newProgressRenter
    }

    private var _progressAar = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val progressAar: MutableLiveData<String> = _progressAar

    fun saveProgressAar(newProgressAar: String){
        _progressAar.value = newProgressAar
    }

    init {
        seekbarRenterProgress.value = 5
        seekbarAarProgress.value = 5
    }
}
```

The seekBar and textview look like this in my xml:

```
                <SeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/AarSerieSeekBar"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:max="50"
                    android:min="0"
                    android:progress="@={viewmodel.seekbarAarProgress}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.306"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/AarTall"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@={`` + viewmodel.seekbarAarProgress}"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="@{viewmodel.seekbarAarProgress != null? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.619"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/AarSerieSeekBar"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />
```

For test if the second fragment can read the data I wrote this code that observe the data and sends it to a textview that comes up when you run the app in a emulator:

```
AnnuitetViewModel.loanNumber.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, binding.tvTest::setText)
AnnuitetViewModel.progressRenter.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, binding.tvTest2::setText)
AnnuitetViewModel.progressRenter.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, binding.tvTest3::setText)
```